# How to add Redis to a Docker Container?

Tags: ruby, docker, redis

I have a Sinatra app that works fine in Docker:

```
# Image
FROM ruby:2.3.3
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y net-tools


# Install app
ENV APP_HOME /app
ENV HOME /root
RUN mkdir $APP_HOME
WORKDIR $APP_HOME
COPY Gemfile* $APP_HOME/
RUN bundle install
COPY . $APP_HOME


# Configure App
ENV LANG en_US.UTF-8
ENV RACK_ENV production

EXPOSE 9292


# run the application
CMD ["bundle", "exec", "rackup"]
```

But when I try to add Redis:

```
# Redis
RUN         apt-get update && apt-get install -y redis-server
EXPOSE      6379
CMD         ["/usr/bin/redis-server"]
```

Redis does not seem to start.

So, what is a good way to add Redis to a Ruby (`FROM ruby:2.3.3`) Docker container?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Split this into two containers. You can use docker-compose to bring them up on a common network. E.g. here's a sample docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2'

services:
  sinatraapp:
    image: sinatraapp:latest
    ports:
    - 9292:9292
  redis:
    image: redis:latest
```

The above can include more options for your environment, and assumes your image name is sinatraapp:latest, change that to the image you built. You'll also need to update your sinatra app to call redis by the hostname redis instead of localhost. Then run `docker-compose up -d` to start the two services.

Comment: Yes, I saw that it is easier and better to do it this way.

Comment: For the future searchers, the `redis` key won't work in this case. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/42380642/336920

Answer (score 2):

[There can be only one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23692470/why-cant-i-use-docker-cmd-multiple-times-to-run-multiple-services) `CMD` command in your `Dockerfile`. Moreover what you want to do is a [little more complex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19948149/can-i-run-multiple-programs-in-a-docker-container) than you might think.

P.S. The above are stackoverflow links.

Comment: It seems that the "Docker way" would be to have 2 containers. Simpler and easier.

Comment: Yes that's the correct and easiest way if you don't have any serious complications.