# How to connect to a Redis container using Docker Compose?

Tags: docker, redis, docker-compose

This `docker-compose.yml` seems to work OK:

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    image: web-app
    command: bundle exec rackup
    ports:
     - "9292:9292"
    links:
      - redis
  redis:
    image: redis
```

Command:

```
docker build -t web-app .; docker-compose up
```

The Web App is expecting a REDIS_URL config. Web App Dockerfile:

```
ENV REDIS_URL redis:6379
```

It seems that the Web App cannot connect to the Redis:

```
Redis::CannotConnectError - Error connecting to Redis on 127.0.0.1:6379 (Errno::ECONNREFUSED):
```

So, what is the Redis URL for the Web App?

Do I need to expose the Redis port (6379)?

EDIT:

Thanks to @Andy Shinn, I see the redis url should be `redis://6379`.
Now I get `Errno::EINVAL - Invalid argument - connect(2) for 0.0.24.235:6379`. This may have to do with Redis v 3.2.8. I'll try another version and see if it works.

EDIT #2:

3.2.8 works fine with the app on my local machine, so that is not the issue.

Comment: Is redis running at that point? What happens if you start them all, and then restart the `web` after a bit -> that way you know that `redis` has been started.

Comment: That error says the `web` service is trying to connect to redis at the local IP (127.0.0.1) and not the `REDIS_URL` which should be the `redis` DNS name from the link. What kind of application is this? Is it designed to use the `REDIS_URL`? It would be helpful to post a bit more about the application (`Dockerfile`, how it uses the `REDIS_URL`, etc).

Comment: Yes, it is configured to use the `REDIS_URL`. It's a Sinatra app. Other configs work, and production has a `REDIS_URL`.

Comment: @Nanne - Does not seem to be a timing issue. Redis starts before the web app.

Comment: Is `0.0.24.235` the IP it's attempting to reach now, or a copy/paste error?

Comment: I'd also change `link` to `depends_on`, the link syntax is being phased out.

Comment: @BMitch - That is the correct IP. I guess thats how `links` works...? I'll try `depends_on`.

Comment: That IP doesn't look right at all to me, if it was 10.0.24.235 it would make sense. Get the redis container ip from a `docker inspect $redis_container_id` (use `docker ps` to get the id) and compare to what the app is trying to use.

Answer (score 55):

The issue is that `redis` is "variable" that will be interpolated in the Dockerfile.

```
ENV REDIS_URL redis:6379
```

But the Redis URL should start with the ***literal*** `redis`.

So, the fix is updating the docker compose:

```
redis_db:
  image: redis:3.2.8
```

The desired config is:

```
REDIS_URL=redis://redis_db:6379
```

Thanks to BMitch and Andy Shinn for helping me figure this out.

Comment: FWIW, Mongo URL's can have the same issue because they start with `mongodb://`.

Comment: do you have any idea how REDIS_URL looks like if i set a password?

Comment: @calvin redis://user:secret@localhost:6379/0?foo=bar&qux=baz

Comment: this saved a lot of time. thank you

Answer (score 0):

The create client config is updated in the new version

doc for the same https://github.com/redis/node-redis/blob/master/docs/client-configuration.md