# Docker-Compose, How To Connect Java Application With Custom Docker Network On Redis Container

Tags: docker, networking, redis, docker-compose

I have a java application, that connects through external database through custom docker network
and I want to connect a Redis container.

[docker-redis github topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42376867/how-to-connect-to-a-redis-container-using-docker-compose)

I tried the following on the application config:

```
1 localhost:6379
2 app_redis://app_redis:6379 
3 redis://app_redis:6379
```

nothing works on my setup

docker network setup:

```sh
    docker network create -d bridge --subnet 192.168.0.0/24 --gateway 192.168.0.1 mynet
```

[Connect to a Database Running on Your Docker Host](https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/docker-tip-35-connect-to-a-database-running-on-your-docker-host)

**PS:** this might be off-topic, how I can add the network on docker-compose instead of external

docker-compose:

```
    services:
        app-kotin:
            build: ./app
            container_name: app_server
            restart: always
            working_dir: /app
            command: java -jar app-server.jar
            ports:
                - 3001:3001
            links:
              - app-redis
            networks: 
                - front
        app-redis:
            image: redis:5.0.9-alpine
            container_name: app-redis
            expose:
                - 6379 

    networks:    
        front:        
            external:
                name: mynet
```

with the setup above how can I connect through a Redis container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both containers need to be on the same Docker network to communicate with each other.  The `app-kotin` container is on the `front` network, but the `app-redis` container doesn't have a `networks:` block and so goes onto an automatically-created `default` network.

The simplest fix from what you have is to also put the `app-redis` container on to the same network:

```yaml
    app-redis:
        image: redis:5.0.9-alpine
        networks:
            - front
```

The Compose service name `app-redis` will then be usable as a host name, from other containers on the same network.

You can simplify this setup considerably.  You don't generally need to manually specify IP configuration for the Docker-private networks.  Compose can create the network for you, and in fact it will create a network named `default` for you.  ([Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) discusses this further.)  `links:` and `expose:` aren't used in modern Docker networking; Compose can provide a default `container_name:` for you; and you don't need to repeat the `working_dir:` or `command:` from the image.  Removing all of that would leave you with:

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  app-kotin:
    build: ./app
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '3001:3001'
  app-redis:
    image: redis:5.0.9-alpine
```

The server container will be able to use the other container's Compose service name `app-redis` as a host name, even with this minimal configuration.

Comment: adding redis service to the same network. it works now. and using the service name as the host-name in the app configuration

but using the default network created by docker-compose, connecting to host-container db isnt working.


can you show the right way to configure a network,  instead of using externally created docker network, I configure it using docker-compose?

thanks, greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you have a database running on the non-Compose `mynet` network then you do need a top-level `networks:` block like you originally had pointing at it, but you can use that block to [configure the `default` network](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#configure-the-default-network) instead of creating a new network.