# Run multiple commands while starting docker services

Tags: python, docker, gunicorn

I am trying to run two different commands when doing docker-compose up.

My `command:` parameter looks like:

```
gunicorn --reload analytics_api:api --workers=3 --timeout 10000 -b :8083 && exec python /analytics/model_download.py
```

But when I run this the container fails with the error:

> gunicorn: error: unrecognized arguments: && exec python
>   /analytics/model_download.py

The second part of the command `python /analytics/model_download.py`, is used to download some dependencies from a sharedpath to a directory inside the container.

I want to run it while the service is up, not during the build.

What is going wrong here?

Comment: Execute the `exec python /analytics/model_download.py` command first and then run the `gunicorn` command

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't I use Docker CMD multiple times to run multiple services?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23692470/why-cant-i-use-docker-cmd-multiple-times-to-run-multiple-services)

Comment: Can you run the "download" step as a `RUN` step in your Dockerfile?  That'd be cleaner and avoid this problem.

Comment: @DavidMaze That will make the image huge, and after each retraining, the build should be made, which is not advised

Comment: @julian I want to run it in the docker-compose file while starting the container, not during the build.

Comment: @techytushar when I do so, the container `exited with code 0`

Comment: I think the entrypoint/ CMD in the Dockerfile can be overridden in the manifest. So same logic would apply there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `bash -c` before the command solved the problem.

The command value will look like:

`bash -c "python model_download.py && gunicorn --reload analytics_api:api -- workers=3 --timeout 10000 -b :8083"`

Answer (score 0):

One way can be to have a startup shell script as the `command` which has both these entries

startup.sh

```
#start this in background if the other process need not wait for completion
exec python /analytics/model_download.py &
gunicorn --reload analytics_api:api --workers=3 --timeout 10000 -b :8083

while true 
 do
   sleep 5
done
```

Comment: When I give it inside the sh file the container exits with exit code 0. Looks like after running the commands the container closes itself.

Comment: Don't let the script file exit by keeping a while loop which sleeps..

Comment: Can you detail it?