# Error while running a unit test of an API in docker container

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile, fastapi

i am working on Docker project : we have api ( fast api ) which is working  fine after pulling the image then running the the container:

```sh
docker image pull toto/fastapi:1.0.0
docker container run -p 8000:8000 toto/fastapi:1.0.0
```

the API is available on port 8000 of the host machine
--> I would like to run the tests on that API in a container , using Dockerfile :

1. I created a folder : that contains  the Dockerfile and my test script :

```
toto_image_test1: ____
                    |______Dockerfile
                    |______script.py
```

Remark: when I run my script of test locally with going through the container : it is working correctly and generating the output that I am looking for .

2. I have built  the image related to the api test :

```sh
docker image build -f Dockerfile . -t toto_image_test1:latest
```

then when i run  the container I face an issue:
here is the container that I run :

```sh
docker container run -it -d toto_image_test1:latest
```

Here is the content of my Dockerfile :

```
FROM toto/fastapi:1.0.0
ARG address
ENV address = '0.0.0.0'
RUN echo $address
CMD ["Bash"]
ARG port
ENV port = 8000
RUN echo $port
CMD ["Bash"]
ADD script.py /home/ubuntu/toto_image_test1/script.py
COPY   script.py   /home/ubuntu/script.py
WORKDIR /home/ubuntu
CMD python3 /home/ubuntu/script.py
RUN python3 /home/ubuntu/script.py &
```

Here is the first part of my script:

```
import os
import requests
import json
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
from requests.packages.urllib3.util.retry import Retry
from time import sleep
api_port = os.environ.get('port')
print("api_port",api_port)
api_address = os.environ.get('address')
print("api_address",api_address)
pwd = os.environ.get('PWD')
print ( 'le path actuel ssssssssss',pwd)

# requête authentication
r = ''
while r == '':
    try:
        r = requests.get(url='http://0.0.0.0:8000/permissions'.format(address=api_address,` `port=api_port),params= {'username': 'XX','password': '****'})
        print("request rrrrrrrr",r)
        break
    except:
        print("Connection refused by the server..")
        print("Let me sleep for 5 seconds")
        print("ZZzzzz...")
        #print("URL is ",url)
        print("r is rrrrrrrrr ",r)
        time.sleep(5)
        print("Was a nice sleep, now let me continue...")
        continue
```

The issue is that I always find that 'r' is always empty: the query never gives a result inside the container, however it is working fine locally.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO ;) First of all, it must be considered you can't call CMD several times in one `dockerfile` due to which has been mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23692470/why-cant-i-use-docker-cmd-multiple-times-to-run-multiple-services)!
But as I found out you are going to run an API and then test it through a custom scenario in `script.py`, I recommend writing the RUN.sh file for running your Service and test script before anything else and call it at the end of `dockerfile` with only one `CMD` directive. In addition, it's best practice to use `COPY` instead of `ADD` when you're copying from the local file system to the image.

Comment: Hello , thank you for the answer , i have updated the Dockerfile as below , but unfortunately i still have the same issue : always  "r" is empty :
`FROM datascientest/fastapi:1.0.0
ARG address
ENV address = '0.0.0.0'
RUN echo $address
ARG port
ENV port = 8000
RUN echo $port
COPY server.py /home/ubuntu/my_docker_image_test1/server.py
COPY   server.py   /home/ubuntu/server.py
WORKDIR /home/ubuntu
CMD python3 /home/ubuntu/server.py
RUN python3 /home/ubuntu/server.py &`