# Run bash command from docker-compose - "bash not found"

Tags: bash, docker-compose

I am trying to run a bash command on startup of a docker-compose service:

```yaml
version: '3.6'
services:
    web:
        ...
    runner:
        image: gitlab/gitlab-runner:latest
        command: bash -c "gitlab-runner register -n --url ..."
```

Following the answers from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30064175/9115920) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71789000/9115920) other similar answers, I have tried this command with `bash`, `sh`, `/bin/bash` and `/bin/sh` and they all result in this error:

```
FATAL: Comand bash not found.
```

If I do not run the command in docker-compose, and instead `docker exec -it ... /bin/bash`, I can get a bash terminal in the container and run the command no problem from inside the container.

I am not sure why it cannot find the `bash` command when running from the docker-compose.yml file

Comment: `command: bash -c "gitlab-runner ..."` doesn't make sense: In order to parse it into an argv like `["bash", "-c", "gitlab-runner ..."]`, you need to have a shell already. Why start a second shell when you already _have_ a shell, then? (It would make more sense as `command: [ "/bin/bash", "-c", "gitlab-runner ..." ]`, as in _that_ form you're not implicitly starting a shell to run the string passed as a single command).

Comment: I am trying to run the command after the container has started, automatically. Is there a different way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I'd directly add a `volume` to mount in the script you're after and run it

```bash
#!/bin/bash
echo "my script ran - remember to chmod +x if I don't run at first"
```

```yaml
    runner:
      image: gitlab/gitlab-runner:latest
      # customize as needed
      volumes: src:/opt/mysrc
      command: /opt/mysrc/mycommand.sh
```