# How to run 2 commands in a Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a Dockerfile and it ends with CMD command like below;

```
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

So I want to add another command like below;

```
CMD java -javaagent:/work/dd-java-agent.jar
```

2 CMD entry not allowed for Dockerfile, how can I re-organize these commands in a single line?

Thanks!

Comment: Are these blocking commands? Which one do you want to run first?

Comment: I guess it doesn't matter, second one is Datadog agent.

Comment: You'd almost always run two separate commands in two separate containers.  In this setup it's not obvious what the two parts would have in common (one's a Node application and one Java) so I'd probably even run them with two separate images.

Comment: [Why can't I use Docker CMD multiple times to run multiple services?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23692470/why-cant-i-use-docker-cmd-multiple-times-to-run-multiple-services) includes both some explanation and some other approaches.

Answer (score 0):

Running two things in the same container is actually a bit of an anti-pattern for containers. However you can of course still do this and it's covered in the [docker documnetation](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container/).

You use a script that does this like so:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Start the first process
npm start &
  
# Start the second process
java -javaagent:/work/dd-java-agent.jar &
  
# Wait for any process to exit
wait -n
  
# Exit with status of process that exited first
exit $?
```

Your dockerfile will look something like this:

```
COPY my_wrapper_script.sh my_wrapper_script.sh
CMD ./my_wrapper_script.sh
```

Comment: How about something like this? --> CMD java -javaagent:/work/dd-java-agent.jar && npm start

Comment: @yatta you can, but with only one &. && means it will be executed after the end of the first command.. that as far as i understood it will never end. one & instead will launch it as a background process. anyway, i think the script proposed by Rick Rackow is far more clean and maintainable

Comment: @rick This script&Dockerfile somehow gives error, "Container image "asdasdsa" already present on machine".