# Auto start Nginx and Gunicorn in Docker

Tags: django, docker, nginx

I am a student, and I am currently trying to deploy my Django application on Docker Ubuntu using Nginx and Gunicorn. However, when I restart the container, both Nginx and Gunicorn are also turned off. I have to use the command "docker attach " to enter the container and run the commands `service nginx start` and `systemctl start gunicorn`. Is there any way to automatically start Nginx and Gunicorn when the container is restarted? Thank you sincerely.
[[This is the configuration file.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xrEUM.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HC7Ol.png)

I have tried writing a start.sh file like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Start Nginx
service nginx start

# Start Gunicorn
systemctl start gunicorn

exec "$@"
```

and Dockerfile

```
FROM my_image

COPY start.sh /start.sh
RUN chmod +x /start.sh


EXPOSE 80

CMD ["/start.sh"]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow!
This question is duplicate of following question:
https://serverfault.com/questions/685697/multiple-commands-in-docker-cmd-directive

Comment: Commands like `service` and `systemctl` don't really work in Docker.  Can you split this into two separate containers instead?  (I'm not clear that Nginx will accept the PNG-format configuration, and you might [edit] the question to include it in plain text instead.)

Comment: [Why can't I use Docker CMD multiple times to run multiple services?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23692470/why-cant-i-use-docker-cmd-multiple-times-to-run-multiple-services) probably gives the clearest set of common answers of the various related questions on Stack Overflow, but it's usually considered a best practice (and is simpler) to run only one program in a container, and to use multiple single-process containers together.